# comparing multiple values given to a key in python

Tags: python, hadoop, key-value

I am actually trying to develop a mapper and reducer using python for a certain data.
I have written the mapper code which would give the store name and the cost of the transaction that was done at the store.

For example:

`Nike $45.99
Adidas $72.99
Puma $56.99
Nike $109.99
Adidas $85.99`

Here the key is the store name and the value is the cost of transaction.
Now I am trying to write the reducer code which would compare the cost of transactions at each store and give the highest transaction at each store.

Now the output that I want to get is

`Nike $109.99
Adidas $85.99
Puma $56.99`

My question is how can I compare the different values given to a key in python?

Comment: How is your data formatted. Is it loaded into a dict, is it saved to a txt file etc...?

Comment: It is saved in a text file which I would import later.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `MapReduce` paradigm is a key-value pairs that each mapper should output in the exact format.

As for the reducer, the hadoop framework guarantees that each reducer using a shuffle-sort algorithm, will get all the values for a certain key, so there's no way that two different reducers will get different entries from the same key.

However, a reducer can have more than one key values to process.

As for your question, let's assume you have 3 different values for the same key, for example:

```
Nike $109.99
Nike $45.99
Nike $294.99
```

The reducer will first get 2 values, so your reducer function based on your key will get the values:

- `$109.99`
- `$45.99`

and will need to output the highest one using simple comparison, and the output should be `$109.99` which will be the input for the 2nd time your reducer function will be running, this time with the input:

- `$109.99`
- `$294.99`

And again, using the comparison you should output the highest value, which is: `$294.99`

As for the code, you will need a very simple function, something like:

**EDIT: I assume your delimiter is tab, but you can change the format to whatever you are using**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

current_word = None
current_max_count = 0
word = None

# input comes from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    # remove leading and trailing whitespace
    line = line.strip()

    # parse the input we got from mapper.py
    word, count = line.split('\t', 1)

    # convert count (currently a string) to int
    try:
        count = int(count)
    except ValueError:
        # count was not a number, so silently
        # ignore/discard this line
        continue

    # this IF-switch only works because Hadoop sorts map output
    # by key (here: word) before it is passed to the reducer
    if current_word == word:
        if count > current_max_count:
            current_max_count = count
    else:
        if current_word:
            # write result to STDOUT
            print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_max_count)
        current_max_count = count
        current_word = word

# do not forget to output the last word if needed!
if current_word == word:
    print '%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_max_count)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Avihoo

Answer (score 0):

```
def largets_value(_dict):
    d = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(_dict.keys()):
        d[v] = max(_dict.values()[i])
    return d

def dict_from_txt(file, sep):
    d = {}
    f = [x.rstrip().replace('$', '').split(sep) for x in open(file, 'rb').readlines()]
    for i in f:
        if i[0] in d:
            d[i[0]].append(float(i[1]))
        else:
            d[i[0]] = [float(i[1])]
    return d

def dict_from_iterable(iterable, sep):
    d = {}
    f = [x.rstrip().replace('$', '').split(sep) for x in iterable]
    for i in f:
        if i[0] in d:
            d[i[0]].append(float(i[1]))
        else:
            d[i[0]] = [float(i[1])]
    return d

data = ['Nike $45.99',
        'Adidas $72.99',
        'Puma $56.99',
        'Nike $109.99',
        'Adidas $85.99']
print largets_value(dict_from_iterable(data, ' '))
#Uncomment next line and delete the previous to use for yourself
#print largets_value(dict_from_txt('my_file', ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop should be sorting the output of your mapper before passing it to your reducers. Given that you can use `itertools.groupby()` to group like keys into a list, and then select the biggest from each grouped list:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from itertools import groupby

for store, transactions in groupby((line.split() for line in sys.stdin),
                                   key=lambda line: line[0]):
    print(store, max(float(amount[1].replace('$', '')) for amount in transactions))
```

This of course assumes that the output of your mapper consists of two white space separated fields for store and transaction value.